# How to upgrade vagrant precise32 to newer version?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I attempted to run a Vagrant machine but ran into errors because I had Vagrant 1.0.1 installed.  I then uninstalled and installed Vagrant 1.2.2.  However when I run vagrant up I get an error.

```
$ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
The box 'precise32' is still stored on disk in the Vagrant 1.0.x
format. This box must be upgraded in order to work properly with
this version of Vagrant.
```

I attempted vagrant init but also got an error.

```
$ vagrant init precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box

`Vagrantfile` already exists in this directory. Remove it before
running `vagrant init`.
```

How can I upgrade my precise32 box to a new version of Vagrant?

Answer (score 15):

Run

```
vagrant box repackage precise32 virtualbox
```

Comment: Warning: this has a side effect of leaving a large file (size probably depends on your VM, I got a 640 meg file) called `package.box` in your current working directory.  And if you had such a file already, it'll be silently overwritten (I conclude this by finding just one package.box, despite repackaging three vagrant boxes).

Answer (score 0):

Boxes packaged using vagrant 1.1+ has an extra file called metadata.json as per the [docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/format.html).

Try to manually create a `metadta.json` file under `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/precise32/virtualbox` with contents

```
{"provider": "virtualbox"}
```

Try again and see if you still have the problem.

If it doesn't help, the only way I can think of is to remove the box and add it again using new vagrant version. You don't have to destroy the boxes, even if they don't work with vagrant any more, you can still operate them using `VBoxManage` and VirtualBox GUI.

Comment: You also have to move the other files (box-disk1.vmdk  box.ovf  Vagrantfile) into the virtualbox/ subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the vagrant directory structure has changed between these versions. You add a subdirectory called virtualbox, and then add a metadata.json file into this with contents like '{ "provider": "virtualbox" }'.

Here is a gist with a bash script you can use to automatically do this, and print the changes to your screen.

```
wget -q -O - https://gist.github.com/xrd/6055536/raw/8398322313a7e8a60ee8f9ad4d6a87d50ee55b8d/gistfile1.txt | bash
```

The output is actually runnable to reverse the changes, if you desire to revert to what you already had.

This is all detailed in a blog post which might help:

[Upgrading vagrant boxes to 1.2](http://webiphany.com/2013/07/22/upgrading-vagrant-boxes-to-12.html)

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.